# Determining the cost of multi phase multiway merge sort

Tags: memory-management, databases, mergesort

Let's say I have a disk with an average seek time of 10ms, an average rotational latency of 5ms and a transfer time of 1ms for a 4kb block and the cost of reading the block is the sum of these values. If I have to sort a large relation consisting of 10,000,000 blocks of 4kb each and I have 320 blocks of main memory available for buffering then how would I determine the cost of this multi phase multiway merge sort. I know that in the first phase you need to create sorted runs of 320 blocks each then do 319-way merges. Also because of the small memory, this would usually be in 2 phases but here it will turn into 3 phases.

I also know that the number of sorted sublists is 10,000,000/320 = 31,250 but I'm not sure where to go from here to determine the cost.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to your algorithm, but the number of I/O's required for a well known I/O-efficient merge-sort algorithm is $O((n/B) \log_{M/B}(n/B))$ (see e.g. [here](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~jeffp/teaching/cs7960/A1-merge-sort.pdf)), where $n$ is the input size, $M$ is the internal memory size and $B$ the block size.

Comment: I'm not sure if that could work but I've never learned how to do something like that so I'm not sure. All I know is that because only 320 blocks can fit into the main memory at a time, you'd have to fill the main memory 31,250 times. Then I think you do something regarding the average time it takes to read a block.

Comment: Does the seek time on the disk that depend on the distance of the subsequent blocks in memory? If so, the running time I gave isn't directly applicable, as it doesn't take that into account. (The fact that you need an exact value and not an asymptotic bound also means it isn't that useful).

Comment: Since you apparently know how this 'multi phase multiway merge sort' algorithm works, I don't see where you're stuck. Could you perhaps explain how this algorithm works or a link to its description?